# How to overcome the MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS restriction of WaitForMultipleObjects?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, synchronization

Because of the `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` restriction of `WaitForMultipleObjects` function, I tried to write my own "wait for threads" function but didn't get it work. Can you give me a hint, how to do it?

This is my "wait for threads" function:

```cpp
void WaitForThreads(std::set<HANDLE>& handles)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SECONDSTOWAIT; i++)
    {
        // erase idiom
        for (std::set<HANDLE>::iterator it = handles.begin();
             it != handles.end();)
        {
            if (WaitForSingleObject(*it, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                handles.erase(it++);
            else
                ++it;
        }
        if (!handles.size())
            // all threads terminated
            return;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    // handles.size() threads still running
    handles.clear();
}
```

As long as the thread runs `WaitForSingleObject` returns `WAIT_TIMEOUT` but when the thread terminates the return value is `WAIT_FAILED` instead of `WAIT_OBJECT_0`. I guess the thread handle is no longer valid because `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

The MSDN suggests following solutions:

> - Create a thread to wait on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, then wait on that thread plus the other handles. Use this technique to break the handles into groups of MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS.
> - Call RegisterWaitForSingleObject to wait on each handle. A wait thread from the thread pool waits on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS registered objects and assigns a worker thread after the object is signaled or the time-out interval expires.

But it seems to me that both are too much effort.

**Edit:**
The threads are created with the MFC function `AfxBeginThread`. The returned `CWinThread` pointer is only used to get the associated handle.

```
CWinThread* thread = AfxBeginThread(LANAbfrage, par);
if ((*thread).m_hThread)
{
    threads.insert((*thread).m_hThread);
    helper::setStatus("%u LAN Threads active", threads.size());
}
else
    theVar->TraceN("Error: Can not create thread");
```

Comment: Since you don't show any code that closes `HANDLE`s, and the error code indicates invalid `HANDLE` (perhaps therefore one that has been closed by code not shown) I'd guess there might be a problem in that area.

Comment: Equally important, you don't divulge how the threads were *created*. For example, `_beginthread()` will close the thread handle for you, and thus unless it is actively being waited on *and* is the signaled handle on the resulting wait, an invalid handle result is not on possible, it is *likely*. And if you're *not* doing that and instead using `CreateThread()` or `_beginthreadex()`, then this code leaks handles like a sieve since you never `CloseHandle()` them before the `erase()` or `clear()`.

Comment: The Windows group at Microsoft could easily fix this problem.  But they will not do that, they are just entirely too convinced that anybody that needs this is doing it wrong.  Fair call, the number 64 is a pretty hard limitation in Windows.  There's no way to ever start more than 64 threads in the same processor group.  Given the lack of evidence that you actually need this, the obvious conclusion to draw is that you are in fact doing it wrong.

Comment: *But it seems to me that both are too much effort.* So do it your way instead then.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have edited the question. The threads are created with `AfxBeginThread` (do I need to close the handle here?) and it seems, that the handle, after the tread terminates (the thread function returns) plus one second `Sleep`, is no longer valid (`WaitForSingleObject` returns WAIT_FAILED). If I explicitly wait for one thread with `WaitForSingleObject(threadHandle, 30000)`, the function returns with `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, which is what I expected.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I tried it may way :-), but it didn't work this is why I asked this question.

Comment: @HansPassant: You are certainly right, there are other ways to solve my task (like the [thread pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern), which I considered). For me it seems easier to spawn a thread for each "thing", than handling the 64 restriction.

Comment: [`AfxBeginThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx) creates a `CWinThread` object, returning a pointer to said-same. The *destructor* for `CWinThread` *always* [closes the contained thread handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bbe9bte.aspx), thereby making it invalid for waiting. I bring this up as a hint that the thread object created and managed by MFC will kill off that handle once the thread terminates if the CWinThread is self-destructive. If you're not actively waiting on it at that time, a future wait will be using an invalid handle.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks for the hint, this explains this behavior. After setting `m_bAutoDelete` to `FALSE` it works as expected. I know, I have to delete the CWinThread object now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it seems to me that both are too much effort.

If you want it to work with wait handles, that's what you'll have to do. But if all you need is something that will block until all of the threads have finished, you can use a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or perhaps a [Synchronization Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 Win32 support for semaphores is literally as simple as it gets for what they're intended for. If all you care about is that is thread is *going* to terminate and is done doing anything besides that, this is definitely a viable option. The only caution I advise it to make *sure* the release-op  is in an RAII-protected destructor-triggered object in the main body of the thread-proc.

Comment: If I understand the concept of _Semaphore_ correctly, one can limit the number of running threads. If the limit is reached, the main thread breaks and creates a new thread only if one of the already running threads terminates (and the Semaphore becomes signaled). If no more threads have to be created, the main thread can wait for the last running threads with `WaitForMultipleObjects`. Are you thinking the same?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I got the Semaphore concept (and posted it as answer).

Answer (score 1):

With the [answer from Jim Mischel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969556/237483) I found a solution. [Semaphore Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can solve two issues:

- Waiting for all threads
- Limiting the number of running threads

This is a small, self contained example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

static const LONG SEMCOUNT = 3;

DWORD CALLBACK ThreadProc(void* vptr)
{
    HANDLE* sem = (HANDLE*)vptr; 
    Sleep(10000);
    ReleaseSemaphore(*sem, 1, NULL);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE semh = CreateSemaphore(NULL, SEMCOUNT, SEMCOUNT, 0);

    // create 10 threads, but only SEMCOUNT threads run at once
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        DWORD id;
        WaitForSingleObject(semh, INFINITE);
        HANDLE h = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, (void*)&semh, 0, &id);
        if (!h)
            CloseHandle(h);
    }

    // wait until all threads have released the semaphore
    for (LONG j = 0; j < SEMCOUNT; j++)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(semh, INFINITE);
        std::cout << "Semaphore count = " << j << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "All threads terminated" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```